# Why am I getting and error that says "cannot implicitly convert type 'float' to 'intDamage'?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, compiler-errors

```
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    public GameObject InventoryOB;
    public Text PKText;
    public GameObject PainKillerHold;
    public bool holdingpainkiller;
    public GameObject Player;
    public float charhealth;
    IntDamage amountofPk;
    void Awake()
    {
        amountofPk = Player.GetComponent<IntDamage>().amountofPk;
    }


    void Update()
    {

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.I)) 
        {
        InventoryOB.SetActive(true);
        Player.GetComponent<SC_FPSController>().enabled = false;
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.None;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is the void Awake and the "IntDamage amountofPk;"

I am trying to convert the float to another script, to be more specific the amountofPk float was created in a different script and I want to access that amount in this script also. But in the line under awake I am getting "error cs0029 cannot implicitly convert type 'float' to 'intDamage'.

Comment: Because intdamage is a component from your code. But you then ask for a variable from that which must be a float.

Answer (score 0):

just delete  `.amountofPk;` from :

```
amountofPk = Player.GetComponent<IntDamage>().amountofPk;
```

The final code version looks like

```
amountofPk = Player.GetComponent<IntDamage>();
```